# How to handle kind of nested Promises in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, nested

I'm, relatively new to Promises, so I hope you can help me.
I have the following code:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    .then((salt) =>{
        return  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt)
    })
    .then((hash)=>{
        newUser.password = hash;
        return mariaDB.pool.getConnection()
    })
    .then((conn)=>{
        conn.beginTransaction()
            .then() //here I'm doing some database request
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
                return conn.rollback() //where is this Promise handled?
            })
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        res.json({error: err})
    })
```

I receive a newUser object, which I first pass to bcrypt to encrypt my password.
Then I need to make a transaction to my MariaDB database. But is this kind of "nested Promises" correct? Is there a better solution? Where is the promise "return conn.rollback" handled?

Greetings and Thanks!

Comment: Refactoring this with **async/await** will be more readable and the code will look like sync but it will behave like async.

Comment: can you give me s.th. like a pseudo code? How can I change this to async and await?

Comment: @mcAngular2 you can try using async/await here. Makes life a lot easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it simple like this:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    .then(salt => bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt))
    .then(hash => {
        newUser.password = hash;
        return mariaDB.pool.getConnection()
    })
    .then(conn => {
       return conn.beginTransaction()
          .then(() => {
              // here I'm doing some database request
          })
          .catch( err => {
            conn.rollback();
            throw new Error(err); // this error will be cathed on bottom catch
          });
    })
    .catch(err => res.json({error: err}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10)
.then((salt) =>{
    return  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt)
})
.then((hash)=>{
    newUser.password = hash;
    return mariaDB.pool.getConnection()
})
.then((conn)=>{
    return dbops(conn)
})
.catch((err)=>{
    res.json({error: err})
})
```

// added new function db ops

```
function dbops(conn){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       conn.beginTransaction()
          .then((data)=>{
            //db stuff
            resolve("db stuff done")
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
            conn.rollback()
            reject(err)
        })
     })}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `new Promise` is promise construction antipattern. There's already a promise, no need to create a new one. It also doesn't take a promise from `rollback()` into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
return conn.rollback() //where is this Promise handled?
```

is not handled, this is the problem with this snippet. Nested promises should be chained in order to maintain proper control flow, i.e. returned from `then` and `catch` callbacks:

```
.then((conn)=>{
    return conn.beginTransaction()
    ...
```

Nested promise is required because `conn` should be available in `then` callbacks. A more convenient way to handle this is `async..await`, this allows to flatten nested promises:

```
try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt)
    newUser.password = hash;
    const conn = await mariaDB.pool.getConnection()
    try {
        conn.beginTransaction()
        // ...
    } catch (err) {
        await conn.rollback()
    }
} catch (err) {
    res.json({error: err})
}
```

A good thing would be to rethrow an error after `rollback` because it's clear that things went wrong at this point.

Comment: How can i change this suing async and await?

Comment: Something like this. Hope this helps.,

Comment: Just wrap the code above in async function yourFuncName(){};
More about **async/await** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite with **async/await** (making your life easier by getting rid of all those nested promises, thank me later!) would look like this:

```
try {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt);
  newUser.password = hash;
  const conn = await mariaDB.pool.getConnection();
  try {
    const transaction = await conn.beginTransaction();
    // your db calls
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return conn.rollback();
  }
} catch (err) {
  res.json({error: err})
}
```

Please make sure you wrap this block within an `async` function. For example, for self-invoking function use:

```
(async() => {
 // the block of code using await ...
})();
```